# PHP: DIY WebDav Server

Tags: php, webdav

I know that there are a number of libraries available, but I am trying to learn more about the WebDav protocol itself for a project I’m developing.

For stage 1, I would like to implement a virtual read-only file system in PHP, presenting as a WebDav server.

As far as I can tell, it would need to be able to:

- list virtual files & directories
- change directories
- print the contents of a single file

I’ve found a number of sources, but they either try to do too much or gloss over the implementation of the protocol itself.

Can someone explain or point me to a source that might answer the following:

- What are the steps in the communication between the client & server?
- How does PHP receive a request, and how should the response be formatted?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I originally started [sabre/dav](http://sabre.io/) I still made sure to read the entire [rfc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918) first. You really need to have a good idea of all the features, the data model and how they work together.

After that, you probably only really need to look at the `PROPFIND`, `OPTIONS` and `GET` methods. One option is to just look at what a client sends your way... figure out based on the rfcs what the response *should* be, and then write the code that sends the correct response.

Another good way to start learning is to hook up an existing webdav client to a webdav server and inspect what kind of messages they send back and forward.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have also got some useful information from your own article at http://evertpot.com/167/. I have started monitoring WebDav communications, and it’s mostly clear. I will have to ask more about the PROPFIND method.

Comment: Wow I had no memory I ever wrote that! :P